# Detect if user try to login from other device in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to make a node js app in which user can login with only single pc if he can try to login on other device then I can notify him just same like netflix device identification. I'm using node js, express and sqlite db.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please review the following article on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask